# Passing values from one java program to another

Tags: java

I wrote a Java program that can execute another Java program during runtime. The program is as follows:

```java
import java.io.*;

public class exec {
    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        int i = 5, j = 6, k = 7;
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));    
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            System.out.println("Enter class name");
            String s = br.readLine();
    
            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
    
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
            String line=null;
            while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch(Exception err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If I execute this program it will prompt the user to enter any class name (Java program) to execute. This is being done using this piece of code `Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);`.

Once the user enters the Java class name, I should be able to pass the values 5,6,7 to the Java class entered by the user. Only one value at a time should be passed and the square of that number should be calculated.

How can I do this?

Comment: *"Can anyone please tell me how to do this?"*  Can you please 1) Ask a specific question.  2) Read and implement all the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html) 3) Use `ProcessBuilder` for code intended for 1.5+ 4) Consider calling the other Java class directly from code (no `Process` involved)  5) Indent code according to the usual conventions.  Code indentation is intended to help the reader, and that code reads like a dog's breakfast.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i'm sorry if u could not understand the question. I've tried editing the question. Go through it now and tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the int argument to your second Java program as follows:

```
String[] cmd = { s, Integer.toString(n) };
Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

... or as a single `String`:

```
Process pro=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("%s %d", s, n);
```

Comment: i've tried this but how should i how should i handle the value of n in the java class i'm calling. I've tried in this way `import java.io.*;
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
 BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
 String ns = rd.readLine();
 int n = Integer.parseInt(ns); 
System.out.println("Square of the number is"+n*n);
}
}`. Should i read the value of 'n' as a command line argument?

Comment: The argument n can be accessed from args[0] as a String; i.e. you will need to re-parse it into an int.

Comment: i have one more doubt. If i use your code i'm able to directly pass the value of n to the java class i'm calling. If i have two values like i=5 and j=6, how can i pass these values to the other java class one at a time?

Answer (score 1):

In the second program you can implement a Server Socket then in your first program you can write a Client Socket which sends messages to second application.

You can see the following documentation: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/